# Per resource Json Formatting asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a REST api using ASP.Net core 1.0.0, and I am currently trying to figure out a way to serialize and deserialize Incoming request body and out going responses.

for example, I have the following

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]ScheduleEvent scheduleEvent)
{
     . 
     .
     .
     return Ok(scheduleEvent);
}
```

The thing is, ScheduleEvent is a database model, so not all the properties should be sent or received from/to the client.

The only solutions I could find are either creating DTO classes and converting the DTO objects to and from model objects, or placing jsonattributes over the object. The first seems like an unnecessary workaround, and the second forces you to make your models depend on json.net, besides the fact that it also makes serialization and deserialization exactly the same. Basicly they all seem like bad solutions - mostly since json.net allows using schemas to invalidate incoming/outgoing json, and If someone were to use it he could create such functionality easily by creating input and output schemas per type or per Controller/Action.

However, JsonConverter doesn't seem like the right way to go, and creating my own json output and input formatters seems like a lot of work, for something that might have a better solution.

So basically, the question is, what is the common way of addressing this problem, and do you know any better solution?

Comment: This is the **exact** reason why you **need** DTOs (or another common term used: "BindingModel" in distinction to DomainModel and ViewModel) and why you should **NEVER** use persistence models outside of a repository. You usually define this "BindingModels" in an assembly called `MyProject.Contracts` which clearly states it's purpose: It acts as contracts between services and service boundaries. While persistence model may change, the binding model is the one which dictates how services communicate with each other

Comment: but this requires you to either convert the BindingModel to and from the model, instead of just deserializing your model, and using it. This either forces you to write more code just to use the BindingModel which is time consuming, and generally not very fun - or to use a library such as AutoMapper, which (I think) uses a reflection to reduce your coding time - which creates an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Less code != good code. What you want to do reduce time but it causes high coupling. Each and every single change to your datamodel **will** break your Api. This is not good design, not very maintainable, not scalable. AutoMapper was made for pretty much such cases, just be aware that AutoMapper is only suitable for Persistance -> DTO or domain -> viewmodel/dto/binding model conversion. It's not suitable for the other way around (i.e. bindingmodel -> persistence or viewmodel -> domain model).

Comment: If you don't do this, you get a leaky abstraction and your persistence model dictates how your have to develop and use your application, very very bad practice and one reason why patterns like DDD were developed to decouple the domain and make it persistence ignorant